# Target DE and Destination DE the same?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpagesurl

I have a DE with three columns with values and two with no values.

[image]

I want to send an email to this DE.
The email contains a link to a Cloudpage landing page with a form & as customers fill the form I want the respective rows updated i.e. column 4 & 5 with their preferences.

My question is, Is this doable?
if yes, then is the below code correct to be used in the Cloud page?

```
%%[ 

VAR @dataExtensionName, @formSubmitted, @Product, @Duration

SET @dataExtensionName = "testingcloudpage"

SET @formSubmitted = IsNullDefault(RequestParameter("submit"), "")

IF @formSubmitted == "submit" THEN

SET @Product = IsNullDefault(RequestParameter("Product"), "")

SET @Duration = IsNullDefault(RequestParameter("Duration"), "")

ENDIF

]%%
```

Also, where do I enter this code? Is it in the HTML editor of the submit button of the cloud landing page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your requirement. I feel below approach is easy to start with,

Firstly to identify the subscriber, pass the subkey this to your cloudpage. 
To accomplish this you must use the combination of [RedirectTo()](https://ampscript.guide/redirectto/) and [CloudPagesURL()](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/) methods as below.

#### Email

```html
SET @subkey = Attribute.GetValue('_subscriberkey')
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(0001,'subkey',@subkey))=%%">Click to update Product details</a>
```

#### Cloudpage

1. You must the the parameters from the Email and form fields both using a common AMPscript method [RequestParameter()](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/)
2. And use the [upsertData()](https://ampscript.guide/upsertdata/) function to Update your DE with values coming from the form.

```html
%%[
SET @Skey = RequestParameter('subkey')
SET @Product = RequestParameter('Product')
SET @Duration = RequestParameter('Duration')

if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then
    SET @upsertCount = upsertData("testingcloudpage",1,"Subskey", @Skey, "Product", @Product, "Duration", @Duration)
endif
]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      %%[ if @upsertCount >= 1 THEN ]%%
         <p>Sucess.</p>
      %%[ if @upsertCount <= 0 THEN ]%%
         <p>Error!.</p>
      %%[ else ]%%
      <h2>Register</h2>
      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
         <label>Product</label>
         <input type="text" name="Product">
         <label>Duration</label>
         <input type="text" name="Duration">
         <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true" />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      %%[ endif ]%%
   </body>
</html>
```

Note: Make sure to update the CLOUDPAGE ID and DE name accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Vishal. i will give this a go and come back to you if it works. ill be on site in a day.

Comment: hi vishal the information is flowing through which is great but the values of the form are getting added into a new row of the target DE instead of updating the row for the respective subkey. So based on my table above product and duration is added into row two and doesn't line up with subskey 123.

Comment: Does the 'Subkey' field is marked as PRIMARY KEY? in your DE!

Comment: yes it is. the rest are all nullable.

Comment: oh! Strange!! How come you can have the duplicate values for the PRIMARY KEY field. Can you double check please.... What I understand from your above statement is you are having `2 rows` with `Subkey = 123` ?

Comment: So what is happening is if you take the table above, the values for product and duration after submitting go on row two under Product and Duration.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share screenshot, however what I understand from the above is as you are NOT getting the SubKey, a new row has been created and values are getting stored in a new row... Can you confirm you have placed the code `SET @subkey = Attribute.GetValue('_subscriberkey')` to get subkey and also try to output this in landing page and check whether it is passed to the cloudpage successfully?

Comment: Hi Vishal, this is now fixed. i had the syntax wrong. thank you for your help mate.

Comment: @RahulG you are welcome n thanks for your confirmation.